# Как открыть ссылки в новой вкладке без перехода?

Tags: javascript, браузер, link

Есть необходимость открывать пакет ссылок из массива в новых вкладках браузера, но БЕЗ перевода пользователя на данные вкладки.(Пользователь должен остаться в окне исполняемого кода) Подскажите, как это возможно реализовать. Пример:

```js
let links = ["https://www.google.com/", "https://jsfiddle.net/", "https://ru.stackoverflow.com/"];

for (let i = 0; i < links.length - 1; i++) {
  window.open(links[i]);
}
```

Почему-то браузер или блокирует переходи, или останавливается после открытия 2-й ссылки. Установка таймера задержки почему-то не решает проблему.

Comment: Встречался с такой проблемой. Долго искал решение и в конце написал обработчику клика по кнопке чтобы он зажимал ctrl при клике по ссылке.

Comment: интересно про Ctrl, но не мой случай. Тут массовое открытие большого количества ссылок введенного в поле ввода.  Как вообще оставлять пользователя на странице..., но что б новая вкладка ему открылась?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По сути никак. Ваш вариант рабочий. Но в целях безопасности, браузеры запрещают подобное. Чтобы не было такого, что вы попадаете на сайт, а вам сразу 10 рекламных вкладок.

Comment: А так что бы остаться на странице на которой исполняется код ? Только открыть вкладки ?

Answer (score 0):

```js
let links = ["https://www.google.com/", "https://jsfiddle.net/", "https://ru.stackoverflow.com/"];

for (let i = 0; i < links.length - 1; i++) {
  window.open(links[i], '_blank').focus();
}
```

Comment: Пользователь НЕ ДОЛЖЕН редиректиться с страницы где выполняется код